# Stretch div to window using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to expand a slider to fit the window using jQuery.

The relevant url is http://bachmann.co.kr/

I used the following script:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function(){
 $('#sliderontop').width($(document).width());
});
```

I found the slider moved to the right. (In mobile version, it moved to the right slightly.)
I tried other methods, but I could not make it done.

I think I missed something.
How can I expand the left side to the left to fit the window?
Do I need to adjust it using CSS media query?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm wonder why not: `#sliderontop{ width: 100vw }`;

Comment: @mitogh. Thanks for your comment. I added #sliderontop{ width: 100vw }; but the issue still appears...

Comment: The problem on your site is the container where the slider is located as you can see on this image, the container (blue box) http://postimg.org/image/3sypotc15/full/ defines where your div should be located, in order to solve your problem you need to put your slide outside of the container.

Comment: @mitogh. Thanks a lot.